# "share with you" or "share you with"

Tags: grammar

Should I say "Here are what I want to share with you" or
"Here are what I want to share you with",

which one sounds more natural?

Thank you.

Comment: Here is what I want to share with you.

Comment: Try  telling your wife "I want to share you with that guy over there".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Share you with is completely wrong. Share something with you means you are going to give something to me, it may even be something you want to tell. But share you with means you are going to share the person with someone else, that is, you are going to give the person to someone else. That makes no sense at all. So I want to share with you is the right one.